# Does the dot Directed Graph allow for subgraphs with a different rankdir?

Tags: drawing, dot, directed-graph

Using the *dot* directed graph language, is it possible to create subgraphs with a different rankdir?

I tried the following, which didn't work.  Both graphs were left to right, despite the presence of rankdir="TB" in the subgraph.

```
digraph g {
    rankdir="LR";
    LEFT->RIGHT;
    clusterrank="local";

    subgraph cluster1 { 
        rankdir="TB";    
        node[style=filled];         
        color=black;
        TOP->BOTTOM;                
    }   
}
```

Is there some other syntax to get a Top/Bottom and Left/Right graph in the same diagram, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like this is a long standing feature request:

- [Archived bug at graphviz.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160426130528/http://www.graphviz.org/bugs/b1279.html)
- [Issue as migrated to Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/887)

Comment: Ah, a canonical "you can't do that".  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a `clusterrank` attribute for subgraphs, try this:

```
clusterrank=local;
```

Comment: Thank you, but could you expand on that?  It's my understanding that clusterrank=local just turns on scanning for cluster subgraphs (i.e. if the name begins with cluster, it's get separate layout treatment).  Adding this in (see above) still gave me a graph where everything was Left to Right.

Answer (score 0):

Desperately wanting the same feature, i Googled and there is a "[trick](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2006q1/003089.html)":
Essentially, you add invisible edges (and nodes if required) to sink the ranks.

Comment: **Forbidden** link :( Could you expand on this?