# Organize boxes horizontally and then vertically in graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz

Is there a way to have boxes show up horizontally in some cases, and vertically in others? (see  [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014092/does-the-dot-directed-graph-allow-for-subgraphs-with-a-different-rankdir)).

Here is the code and output which I am getting:

**code:**

```
/**
** Diagram representing the Simulator Engine
**/
digraph G {
        graph [
            rankdir = "TB"
        ];

        /**
        ** The simulator engine rectangle
        **/
    subgraph cluster_simulator_engine {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        label = "Simulator Engine";

                /**
                ** The first topology
                **/
                subgraph cluster_T1 {
                        color=white;
                        node [style=filled];

                        /**
                        ** The n^th neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T1_N3 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron n";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N3_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N3_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N3_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                /*"T1_N1_S3" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];*/
                        }

                        /**
                        ** The second neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T1_N2 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 2";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N2_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N2_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N2_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                /*"T1_N1_S3" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];*/
                        }


                        /**
                        ** The third neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T1_N1 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 1";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N1_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N1_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N1_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                /*"T1_N1_S3" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];*/
                        }


                        label = "Topology 1";
                }

                /**
                ** The second topology
                **/
                subgraph cluster_T2 {
                        color=white;
                        node [style=filled];

                        /**
                        ** The n^th neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T2_N3 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron n";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N3_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N3_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N3_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                /*"T1_N1_S3" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];*/
                        }

                        /**
                        ** The second neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T2_N2 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 2";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N2_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N2_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N2_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                /*"T1_N1_S3" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];*/
                        }


                        /**
                        ** The third neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T2_N1 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 1";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N1_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N1_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N1_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                /*"T1_N1_S3" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];*/
                        }


                        label = "Topology 2";
                }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image: First Diagram]

Obviously this is far too long. What I want is to move each synapse into its own line (I think it's called a 'rank' in Graphviz-jargon). Apparently, there is no way to do this, but there is a [trick](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/attachments/20060101/88a47858/rblove.obj). Therefore, I take the same code above and introduce invisible edges like so

**code:**

```
/**
** Diagram representing the Simulator Engine
**/
digraph G {
        graph [
            rankdir = "TB"
        ];

        /**
        ** The simulator engine rectangle
        **/
    subgraph cluster_simulator_engine {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        label = "Simulator Engine";

                /**
                ** The first topology
                **/
                subgraph cluster_T1 {
                        color=white;
                        node [style=filled];

                        /**
                        ** The n^th neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T1_N3 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron n";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N3_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N3_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N3_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                "T1_N3_S1" -> "T1_N3_S2" [style=invis];
                                "T1_N3_S2" -> "T1_N3_S3" [style=invis];
                        }

                        /**
                        ** The second neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T1_N2 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 2";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N2_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N2_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N2_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                "T1_N2_S2" -> "T1_N2_S3" [style=invis];
                                "T1_N2_S1" -> "T1_N2_S2" [style=invis];
                        }


                        /**
                        ** The third neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T1_N1 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 1";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N1_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N1_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T1_N1_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                "T1_N1_S1" -> "T1_N1_S2" [style=invis];
                                "T1_N1_S2" -> "T1_N1_S3" [style=invis];
                        }


                        label = "Topology 1";
                }

                /**
                ** The second topology
                **/
                subgraph cluster_T2 {
                        color=white;
                        node [style=filled];

                        /**
                        ** The n^th neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T2_N3 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron n";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N3_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N3_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N3_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                "T2_N3_S1" -> "T2_N3_S2" [style=invis];
                                "T2_N3_S2" -> "T2_N3_S3" [style=invis];
                        }

                        /**
                        ** The second neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T2_N2 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 2";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N2_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N2_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N2_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                "T2_N2_S1" -> "T2_N2_S2" [style=invis];
                                "T2_N2_S2" -> "T2_N2_S3" [style=invis];
                        }


                        /**
                        ** The third neuron
                        **/
                        subgraph cluster_T2_N1 {
                                color=lightgrey;
                                node [style=filled];
                                label = "Neuron 1";

                                /**
                                ** The n^th synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N1_S3" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse n"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The second synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N1_S2" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 2"
                                ];

                                /**
                                ** The first synapse 
                                **/
                                "T2_N1_S1" [
                                    style=filled
                                    shape=box
                                    color=white
                                    label="Synapse 1"
                                ];

                                "T2_N1_S1" -> "T2_N1_S2" [style=invis];
                                "T2_N1_S2" -> "T2_N1_S3" [style=invis];
                        }


                        label = "Topology 2";
                }

    }

}
```

and the output now looks more appealing.

**output:**
[image: Second smaller diagram]

But now there is a huge gap between the synapse boxes. Setting `nodesep=0.1` or `len=0.1` has no effect. Can anyone tell me how to fix this, or how to redesign this.

NOTE: If anyone is curious why I go from 1 to 2 to n, it is because I plan to put an ellipses in there, but I have no clue how to do that...cross that bridge when I get to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [`ranksep`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ranksep) you're looking for - add this line to the attributes for the graph:

```
ranksep = 0.1
```

> In dot, this gives the desired rank separation, in inches. This is the
> minimum vertical distance between the bottom of the nodes in one rank
> and the tops of nodes in the next.